# No Ruby script found in input (LoadError) for bin/dev in Windows 10

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to run bin/dev on a brand new Rails app (7.1.3) using Powershell. I'd rather not use WSL for this one, but if it's needed I will. I do recall that for Rails 6 ones I had to call ruby + script name, but right now this is all I got:

```
PS C:\Users\me\RubymineProjects\depot> ruby .\bin\dev
C:\Ruby32-x64\bin\ruby.exe: no Ruby script found in input (LoadError)
```

Not sure if it's because the bin/dev script is actually a Bash script, but I find it baffling that it doesn't work as intended on a first run. Any tips I could use (besides running WSL if possible)?